# Calculate Average based on multiple condition in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am back with my new excel question.
Lets say I have table like this.

```
    |  A                           |  B  
------------------------------------------
 1  |  ENV                         |  Value
------------------------------------------
 2  |  ABC - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  4
 3  |  XYZ - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  6 
 4  |  ABC -  9/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  1 
 5  |  XYZ - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  10 
 6  |  ABC - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  7
 7  |  XYZ -  9/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  1 
 8  |  ABC -  9/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  10 
 9  |  ABC - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  7 
10  |  XYZ - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM  |  7
```

Now, in Cell C2, I've selected ABC.

**So in cell D2, I want the average (*from col B*) of all the "ABC" (*col A*) where Month = 10 (*col A*) and in cell E2, Max (*from col B*) of all the "ABC" where Month = 10 (*col A*).**

**So, my result in cells D2 and E2 would be 6 and 7 respectively.**

I hope my question and example make sense.

**UPDATE:**
Thank you all for all your help.
Now let's say I am not sure how many rows I'll have on this spreadsheet, so I came up with this formula, but its not working, giving me **#DIV/0!** error.
*Note: I am using formula to get "ABC" and "10" from cell C2.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(
(OFFSET($A$1,1,1,COUNTA($B:$B)-1,1)),
OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,1), (MID(C2,1,(FIND("-",C2))-2)),
OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,1), (MID(C2,(FIND("-",C2)+1),(FIND("/",C2))-(FIND("-",C2)+1))))
```

Even tried this, but same error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((MID(A2:A10,1,(FIND("-",A2:A10))-1))=(MID(C2,(FIND("-",C2)+1),(FIND("/",C2))-(FIND("-",C2)+1))))*
(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A2:A10,7,99)))=(MID(C2,(FIND("-",C2)+1),(FIND("/",C2))-(FIND("-",C2)+1))))*
(B2:B10))/SUMPRODUCT(((MID(A2:A10,1,(FIND("-",A2:A10))-1))=(MID(C2,(FIND("-",C2)+1),(FIND("/",C2))-(FIND("-",C2)+1))))*
(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A2:A10,7,99)))=(MID(C2,(FIND("-",C2)+1),(FIND("/",C2))-(FIND("-",C2)+1)))))
```

Can you help me with this...?

Comment: have you looked up at the solutions proposed here? Why don't they fit your use case? Are you asking something different right now? Should it be the case, I'd suggest you to ask for a new question, as this one will unlikely be helpful to the community...

Comment: @AlexGidan, yes I looked through all the solutions offered here. It is my bad as I din't put all my reqs at first place. I am using your "Intermediary" option as it will help me achieve my goal.
Thanks everyone again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution with Intermediary Values

To solve the issue (I tested the *average* only) I first used 2 intermediary values: this solution is not optimal and there will be many smarter ways to address the issue (e.g. pivot tables).

```
ENV                                Value        Intermediary 1  Intermediary 2  

ABC - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM          4           ABC             10  
XYZ - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM          6           XYZ             10  
ABC -  9/1/2014 1:38:32 PM          1           ABC             9   
XYZ - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM          10          XYZ             10
```

The first intermediary column contains the first 3 chars of ENV column (`=LEFT(A9,3)`), while the second intermediary column contains the month (`=MID(A9,7,2)`). This works *only if* your `ENV` records are fixed size and homogeneous (e.g. your env name has exactly 3 chars).

With this layout, you can compute the average putting in any cell the following formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D9:D12, F9:F12,"=ABC", G9:G12, "=10")
```

Where `D9:D12` is the values interval, `F9:F12` is the 1st intermediary column and `G9:G12` the second intermediary column.

### One Shot Compact Solution (Arrays)

An optimized solution can be found relying on `arrays`. For instance, to calculate the average and the max of an interval based on 2 "vectorial" conditions you can write this one liners:

```
= MAX(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)="ABC")*(MID(A9:A12,7,2)="10"),D9:D12))

= AVERAGE(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)="ABC")*(MID(A9:A12,7,2)="10"),D9:D12))
```

With `A9:A12` your original records, and `D9:D12` is the values interval.

The advantages of this solution are that you don't need any intermediary column and that you can extend this approach to all the other formulas that don't have '`xxxxxIFS`' (it's the case for `MAX`).

**NOTE**: you have to confirm this formula with `CTRL + SHIFT + RETURN` or your formula will fail with `#VALUE` error.

### Live Demo

[image]

Live demo [available here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1189398/live_demo_average.xlsx).

Comment: thank you for help.
I have quick question,
  
Lets say I've "ABC - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM" in cell H2, so how to use "LEFT(A9:A12,3)" instead of hard-coded "ABC" inside
  
= MAX(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)="ABC")*(MID(A9:A12,7,2)="10"),D9:D12))

= AVERAGE(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)="ABC")*(MID(A9:A12,7,2)="10"),D9:D12))

Comment: @Nelly27281, if you mean to use `"ABC"` from the beginning of `H2` instead of the hard coded `"ABC"` you can use `MAX(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)=LEFT($H$2,3))`. I have updated the live demo accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by spiting column A into a date and letters using - Data > Text to Columns with the delimiter " - ".
after you have the new two columns (let say F and G) you can use the function "AVERAGEIF" with a condition that check is the value of the cell in "F" is ABC and the Moth(cell in "G") = 10.
as for the max, you can do the same with MAX(IF....) for column E.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT` will allow you to parse the left-most and date characters from your combined string. A pseudo-MAXIF() can be similarly constructed using `MAX()` and `INDEX()`.

In D2 use `=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A2:A10,3)="ABC")*(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A2:A10,7,99)))=10)*(B2:B10))/SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A2:A10,3)="ABC")*(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A2:A10,7,99)))=10))`

In E2 use `=MAX(INDEX((LEFT(A2:A10,3)="ABC")*(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A2:A10,7,99)))=10)*(B2:B10),,))`

Both `SUMPRODUCT` and `INDEX` like to choke on anything remotely resembling an error when parsing text so keep the cell range references to what your actual data is and avoid blanks.

Your results should look like the following.

[image]

Comment: thank you for help.  I have same question, Lets say I've "ABC - 10/1/2014 1:38:32 PM" in cell H2, so how to use "LEFT(A9:A12,3)" instead of hard-coded "ABC" inside  
    = MAX(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)="ABC")*(MID(A9:A12,7,2)="10"),D9:D12))       = AVERAGE(IF((LEFT(A9:A12,3)="ABC")*(MID(A9:A12,7,2)="10"),D9:D12))

Comment: @Nelly27281 - Are you saying that you would like to use the value in H2 as the alphabetic criteria? If that is the case, simple substitute `LEFT($H$2, 3)` for all instances of `"abc"` in the formula.